# Check whether a string is composed of 3 capital letters and 4 numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check if a string is composed by 3 capital letters and 4 digits.

For example: ABC1234

How do I check it using regular expressions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine something like this would work: https://regex101.com/r/81ZTVQ/1

`^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$`

**Explanation:**

- `[A-Z]` - Case sensitive sequential character (capital A to capital Z) match predicate
- `{n}` - exact number match of preceding match predicate
- `[0-9]` numeric range (in this case, 0 to 9) match predicate

**Test cases:**

```
ABC1234 - Full match
A1BC234 - No match
GFQ9230 - Full match
ACB0000 - Full match
```

**Edit:**

I'd like to include my addition that is somewhat similar to Rawling's answer, yet slightly different.

https://regex101.com/r/81ZTVQ/7

`^(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})(?=(.*\d){4})([A-Z\d]{7})$`

**Explanation**

- `(?=(.*[A-Z]){3})` - Positive lookahead that matches A-Z with any preceding character, 3 times.
- `(?=(.*\d){4})` - Positive lookahead that matches 0-9 with any preceding character, 3 times.
- `([A-Z\d]{7})` - the argument provided must match this predicate - 7 of any combination of A-Z and 0-9. I just prefer having it in a group, hence the grouping.

Working logically backwards, we can have any combination of A-Z and 0-9 as long as the length is 7. Then our positive lookaheads assert the length of the requirements (in this case, 4 digits, 3 capital letters).

**Test Cases for Edit**

```
ABC1234
A1BC234
GFQ9230
ACB0000
AGF1923
A237323
3E44E4E
12344AB
AAAE123
AK348A3
```

Comment: Just a note; this specifies that it's three capital letters *followed by* four numbers. This may be what OP wants, but it won't validate any string with three capital letters and four numbers.

Comment: Good point, I went on an assumption based on OP's example, and did not take into consideration that a string formed with 3 capital letters and 4 numbers in any order might be a case for a success (ie in this case the no match test case). Added test cases to illustrate.

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45202810/563532) - I missed it before; but your answer works for many regex engines, however, the C# engine treats `/` as a literal, rather than the start of a regular expression.

Comment: @Rob Good catch, thanks for that. I have updated the answer to include the consideration for the OP's `C#` tag, and your information about using `/` as a literal.

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for any order, here are two interesting ways of doing it:

```
^(?=(.*\d){4})(?=(.*[A-Z]){3}).{7}$
```

"Exactly seven characters, containing 4 digits and 3 capitals".

```
^(?<d>){4}(?<c>){3}((?<-d>\d)|(?<-c>[A-Z])){7}$
```

"Expect 4 digits and 3 capitals; then ensure we have exactly 7 digits-or-capitals in total, counting each as we go".

Comment: I played around with the regexp for ages, then I got one that worked! Only to realise you had put it in your answer (first option). The only difference is instead of `.{7}`, I put `[A-Z0-9]{7}` and found your version to perform slightly faster on a set of 10 samples (23ms vs 28ms). Nice solution, +1!

Comment: Very clever and compact! The second one worked for me if I removed the closing parenthesis after `(?<c>){3}`.

Answer (score 1):

Another regex: `^[A-Z]{3}\d{4}$`

- `\d` stands for digits
- `^` anchor before first char
- `$` anchor after last char

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a string is composed of 3 capital letters and 4 numbers (assuming those capital letters and numbers can appear anywhere in the string) like this:

```
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(^[A-Z]{3}\d{4}$)|(^[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z]\d{3}$)|(^[A-Z]{2}\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}$)|(^[A-Z]{2}\d{3}[A-Z]\d$)|(^[A-Z]{2}\d{4}[A-Z]$)|(^[A-Z]\d[A-Z]{2}\d{3}$)|(^[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d{2}$)|(^[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d$)|(^[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]$)|(^[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{2}$)|(^[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d$)|(^[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]$)|(^[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]{2}\d$)|(^[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]\d[A-Z]$)|(^[A-Z]\d{4}[A-Z]{2}$)|(^\d[A-Z]{3}\d{3}$)|(^\d[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z]\d{2}$)|(^\d[A-Z]{2}\d{2}[A-Z]\d$)|(^\d[A-Z]{2}\d{3}[A-Z]$)|(^\d[A-Z]\d[A-Z]{2}\d{2}$)|(^\d[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d$)|(^\d[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]$)|(^\d[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d$)|(^\d[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]\d[A-Z]$)|(^\d[A-Z]\d{3}[A-Z]{2}$)|(^\d{2}[A-Z]{3}\d{2}$)|(^\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z]\d$)|(^\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{2}[A-Z]$)|(^\d{2}[A-Z]\d[A-Z]{2}\d$)|(^\d{2}[A-Z]\d[A-Z]\d[A-Z]$)|(^\d{2}[A-Z]\d{2}[A-Z]{2}$)|(^\d{3}[A-Z]{3}\d$)|(^\d{3}[A-Z]{2}\d[A-Z]$)|(^\d{3}[A-Z]\d[A-Z]{2}$)|(^\d{4}[A-Z]{3}$)");
    var samples = new string[]{ "ABC1234", "1A2B3C4", "ABCD123", "aBC1234", "ABC12345" };
    foreach(var sample in samples)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sample + " is " + (rgx.IsMatch(sample) ? "a match" : "not a match"));
    }
```

Output:

> ABC1234 is a match 
>   1A2B3C4 is a match 
>   ABCD123 is not a match 
>   aBC1234 is not a match 
>   ABC12345 is not a match

- *(...)* represents a group
- *^* represents the beginning of a string
- *[A-Z]* represents a capital letter
- *[A-Z]{n}* represents *n* capital letters
- *\d* represents a digit
- *$* represents the end of a string
- *|* is used to indicate that whatever is to the right or left is acceptable

Comment: It is possible to do this without writing out every possible permutation, although it might turn out to be more efficient this way.

Comment: @Rawling, it escaped me how to go about doing it that way. I figured doing it this way with 35 permutations, the regex wouldn't be "way too unreasonably long". But if it were much longer I would probably do some more digging. It would be interesting to see if there's a difference in how well this would compile versus a compact regex.