# Issue with regex (3 capital letters proceeding with 4 numbers)

Tags: c#

I have the following code, which should be passing the regex but it isn't, I'm missing something?

```
if (Regex.IsMatch("ABC1234", "/^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$"))
        {
            //Pasosed Regex
            Console.WriteLine("Pass");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Pass");
        }
```

Output: "No Pass"

Can Anyone help?

Comment: I've just noticed this is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180056). It might be better to provide feedback to the answers via comments instead of opening a new question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `/` from your pattern and it should work.

```
Console.WriteLine(
    Regex.IsMatch("ABC1234", "^[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}$").ToString()
);
// True
```